# Angular filter to remove accents from the word inputed before applying the filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I'm using the following filter to remove accents from the word inputed by the user on an input field, and then use the resulting string on the filter.

```
    .filter('removeAcentos', function(){
    return function (source) {
        var accent = [
            /[\300-\306]/g, /[\340-\346]/g, // A, a
            /[\310-\313]/g, /[\350-\353]/g, // E, e
            /[\314-\317]/g, /[\354-\357]/g, // I, i
            /[\322-\330]/g, /[\362-\370]/g, // O, o
            /[\331-\334]/g, /[\371-\374]/g, // U, u
            /[\321]/g, /[\361]/g, // N, n
            /[\307]/g, /[\347]/g, // C, c
        ],
        noaccent = ['A','a','E','e','I','i','O','o','U','u','N','n','C','c'];

        for (var i = 0; i < accent.length; i++){
            source = source.replace(accent[i], noaccent[i]);
        }

        return source;
    };
})
```

And the code in the view is:

```
    <input type="text" id="curso" name="curso" ng-model="ctrl.curso" validate>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="curso in ctrl.arrayCursos | removeAcentos: ctrl.curso">
        ...
        </li>
    </ul>
```

However, I get the error "source is undefined" and I don't understand why. I also can't use a function inside my controller to be the filter since I'm going to use it in more controllers. I'd like to find where's the error on my code.

`ctrl.curso` is predefined when the user enters the page, so I don't understand the 'source is undefined' error, since `ctrl.curso`is always defined.
   `ctrl.curso`is get via $http request, in case it's relevant.

I was using `|filter: ctrl.curso` before, however know I need to convert ctrl.curso to a string without accents and filtering the list based on this string.

Just to clarify, I'm looking for to filter the array based on the word inputed by the user. However, first I want to convert this word to a string without accents and then apply the filter itself. For example, If the user types the word 'espécie', I want to filter based on the string  'especie'.

Comment: You need to add a check if source is defined and is string `source = source  || ""` in the beginning.

Comment: I tried this, however It gives an error I described on the answer below. The weird thing is that source is never undefined, since `ctrl.curso` is a predefined string when the page loads.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to chain filters. 
First, you need to remove the accent on the user input:

```
search | removeAcentos
```

Then you want to filter your array based on this new value:

```
filter: (search | removeAcentos)
```

Note the parenthesis to ensure filters are applied in the correct order.

Result of the updated ng-repeat:

```
<li ng-repeat="curso in ctrl.arrayCursos | filter: (search | removeAcentos)" />
        {{ curso }}
</li>
```

Link to [Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/16345/)

Comment: I tried this, but the console gives the error `source.replace is not a function`

Comment: Even the JSFiddle is not working ? Which browser are you using ?

Comment: Ouch, now I see the confusion. I don't want to convert all the strings on the array to strings without accents. I want to filter the array based on user inputed string but removing the accents from this string.

Comment: Example: the user enters the word 'espécie', but I want to filter based on the word 'especie'

Comment: Ah, yes, it seems that none of us did understood that. You rework your question. I'm trying to update my answer.

Comment: I think your solution is right, but when I test it the error `Unexpected end of expression: ctrl.arrayCursos |` is thrown. Is this the correct syntax? It's weird because your fiddle works perfectly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86825/discussion-between-nokid-and-bruno-henrique).

Answer (score 0):

Just add in the check:

```
.filter('removeAcentos', function(){
    return function (source) {
        if(!angular.isDefined(source)){ return; }
        var accent = [
            /[\300-\306]/g, /[\340-\346]/g, // A, a
            /[\310-\313]/g, /[\350-\353]/g, // E, e
            /[\314-\317]/g, /[\354-\357]/g, // I, i
            /[\322-\330]/g, /[\362-\370]/g, // O, o
            /[\331-\334]/g, /[\371-\374]/g, // U, u
            /[\321]/g, /[\361]/g, // N, n
            /[\307]/g, /[\347]/g, // C, c
        ],
        noaccent = ['A','a','E','e','I','i','O','o','U','u','N','n','C','c'];

        for (var i = 0; i < accent.length; i++){
            source = source.replace(accent[i], noaccent[i]);
        }

        return source;
    };
})
```

Comment: I added the check, but now there is a 'source.replace is not a function' when I focus on the input field or type any letter. I'll provide some more details in the question.

Comment: You want to do your filter removeAcentos: ctrl.curso AFTER the ng-repeat (in some other element) not trying to filter your array of ctrl.arrayCursos

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. My intention is to filter the ctrl.arrayCursos with the input from the user. I was using `| filter: ctrl.curso` instead, and It worked, but know I need this filter to convert the word entered by the user to a string without accents before filtering.

Comment: Console log source and see what it spits out. It's an array. It's your array ctrl.arrayCursos. I highly recommend you read over some tutorials and do the course on the main angular page as this is a basic concept.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using your filter right.

If you are going to filter collection - use filter for collection and return new collection where property will be filtered off of accents

If you want to use filter for display - don't apply filter to ng-repeat , apply it to your other binding, ie that is your new html:

```
 <li ng-repeat="curso in ctrl.arrayCursos ">
   {{   ctrl.curso | removeAcentos }} 
 </li>
```

Comment: I'm clearly doing some very wrong. As the answer below, the error `source.replace is not a function` appears.